# How to run a native Windows installation on an external harddrive as a virtual machine

Tags: windows, virtualization

I have Windows 10 installed on an external harddrive, since my MBP only has a tiny ssd, where bootcamp or a full vm would be a pain. Now, I want to start Windows from my harddrive without booting into it.

Essentialy I want to use it like a VM (running it alongside MacOS), but can’t figure out how.

I do have parallels desktop installed, but can’t find a way to do that.

Comment: Is your Windows partition a Boot Camp partition, or just pulled from a PC?

Comment: @Tetsujin None of those options. It is a clean install, I did from a windows machine. Bootcamp does not let you install windows on a usb media as far as I know. And even under windows it still comes with a painful process. If want to know if I have the bootcamp option available in parallels, then: no, unfortunately not. :(

Comment: so it's 'pulled from a PC'. Well, if you can put it back in the PC & boot from it, Parallels can import it using [Parallels Transporter Agent](http://kb.parallels.com/en/123929). Alternatively, if it's a clean Windows install, you'd do far better just making it fresh though Parallels directly. I can find no direct method to just take a boot drive & make it work in Parallels.

Comment: Importing it would just clone my install, right? I did not want to make it a VM in the first place, because sometimes I need to boot into windows directly without using it as vm. That would not work with the vm approach as far as I know …

Comment: PCs are not Macs. You cannot make any Windows drive capable of booting two machines... at best you'll have to ring Microsoft every time you change; at worst the driver sets will be so different you'd have to run a repair install every time.